# Pytorch - nn.CrossEntropyLoss

Tags: python, pytorch, loss

I want to apply nn.CrossEntropyLoss

```
output = model(data)
output.shape -> 1,30,7 (batch, frame, class)
label.shape -> 1,30 (batch, frame)
```

In this case,

```
label = label.squeeze(0)
output = output.squeeze(0)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
```

can I solve this?

But if the batch size is 2

output.shape is 2,30,7 and label.shape is 2, 30

How to apply
`loss = criterion(outputs, targets)`

Answer (score 2):

The loss function [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.13/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) can be applied to multi-dim predictions:
[image]

All you need is to make sure your `C` dimension (7 in your case) is the second:

```py
output = output.transpose(1, 2)  # B,30,7 -> B,7,30
loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
```

You do not need to change `targets` at all.